# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send' for my Discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
# bot.py
import os

import json
import discord
from discord import guild
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


def writeToJSON(path, fileName, data):
  filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
  with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
      json.dump(data, fp)


with open('config.json') as f:
  config = json.load(f)

path = './'
fileName = 'config'
data = {}


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
  print(" {} is set as the server status channel.".format(config['statusChannel']))

  channel = config['statusChannel']
  await channel.send('This is the status channel.')


@bot.command()
async def setstatus(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send('The server status channel has been set to ' + arg)
  newArg =""

  for character in arg:
      if character.isalnum():
          newArg += character

  data['statusChannel'] = newArg
  writeToJSON(path, fileName, data)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm just trying to get the bot to send a message in the channel that I have set as the server status. I have the channel ID saved in a json file and I'm able to get the ID to print, just cant seem to send a message to that channel. Also if there is a cleaner way to save the channel ID that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My channel ID from the JSON file was a string. Used `int()` to convert it to int.